# Access VBA Findfirst with Dlookup Syntax Error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am getting an error **Syntax Error(Missing Operator) in expression** for this piece of code

```
For i = 0 To Me.listMachineSubSystem.ListCount - 1
    rs.FindFirst "[Machine ID]=" & ID & "[MachineSystem]=" & DLookup("[MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i))

   rs1.AddNew
   rs1![MachineSubsystem] = Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(1, i)
   rs1![Machine Sytem ID] = rs![Machine System ID]
   rs1.Update
 Next i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to account for spacing, use the `AND` keyword when checking multiple conditions, and use delimiters where needed (strings).

If `MachineSystem` is a number:

```
rs.FindFirst "[Machine ID]= " & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]=" & DLookup("[MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i))
```

If `MachineSystem` is a string:

```
rs.FindFirst "[Machine ID]= " & ID & " AND [MachineSystem]= '" & DLookup("[MachineSystem]", "tblMachineSystem", "[Machine System ID]=" & Me.listMachineSubSystem.Column(2, i)) & "'"
```

Comment: Machine system is a string and when i type in your code , i get an error saying expected: end of statement

Comment: My mistake, The code works like a charm . Thank You very much